# What is a good Python configuration file format that can be edited by one script easily and read by another script easily and safely?

Tags: python, json, configuration, semaphore

Let's say I have two Python scripts. One script is a web interface that enables a human to edit a configuration file. Another script is one that does various things in the background based on the configurations defined in that file, which it reloads every few seconds in a loop.

What is a good format for such a configuration file? I want the format to be human-readable and human-editable, while also being easy to write to and read from without conflicts.

At present, I'm thinking that the `json` module might be a good option, whereby the configuration is essentially a dictionary saved in plaintext to a file and read from that plaintext file into a dictionary. Is this a safe approach? Is there a better approach? Are there going to be problems is one script tries to read from the file while the other is writing to the file? How should this be addressed?

So, as a simple example, here are two scripts. One writes a configuration to a JSON plaintext file and one reads the configuration from the file:

## writer

```
import random

import json

while True:
    config = {"a": 1, "b": random.randint(1, 2)}
    with open("config.json", "w") as file_config:
        json.dump(config, file_config)
```

## reader

```
import json

while True:
    with open("config.json") as file_JSON:
        config = json.load(file_JSON)
    print(config)
```

When both of these scripts are run at the same time, the reader script quickly produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2_script.py", line 5, in <module>
    config = json.load(file_JSON)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How should this be addressed?

Comment: json or yaml...

Comment: @StephenRauch Thanks. How do these cope with the scenario of one script writing to them at the same time as another script reading from them, as described?

Comment: They are just files.  Use a file lock.

Comment: @StephenRauch Is there some standard library solution for this? I see a lot of home-rolled code for it, but I want something simple, Pythonic and safe.

Comment: Locking is a big and non-trivial problem. Very dependent on circumstances.  I do not believe you will find an off the shelve answer that is simple.  These are some of the problems that Databases are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for two features:

1. human-readable configuration file
2. support for one process to write the file while others are reading it

I don't know of an easy solution for both those features, but I can make some suggestions.

1. Do some research into file locking for your platform. That's probably the best option for getting exactly what you want.
2. Consider using a SQLite database instead of a human-readable configuration file. SQLite [supports](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) multiple readers and a single writer process. You could write a command line tool to dump the config for users to review.
3. Try a "good enough" solution that tries to read the file, and deals with any problems from reading incomplete files. Some tricks to consider are adding an "end of file" marker or check sum to be sure you haven't read an incomplete file, as well as writing the file under a temporary name, then renaming it to the active name. After a failure, sleep and retry.
4. Communicate between the processes to notify them when it's safe to read the file, or just send the configuration data directly to each process. If the web service launches the background processes, they could use a Queue or a process Pool. Alternatively, they could communicate through a named pipe.

As for the format, I would consider three options:

1. INI format - old fashioned, but it's supported by the built-in `configparser` module
2. YAML format - I prefer this over JSON, because it supports comments
3. JSON format - popular, but no support for comments: you either have to use a special attribute name like "comment" or strip out the comments before parsing the file